# How to ensure that tickets will not be sold more than allowed?

Tags: c#, mysql, .net-core, entity-framework-core, e-commerce

How do the companies that sell tickets guarantee that no more tickets will be sold?

For example, you have 40 available and sold 39, 2 people at the same time start to buy, both will have the information that that ticket is available, but as soon as one person completes the purchase, the other would still have the false information that has ticket available and the purchase would not be blocked.

How to solve this?

Comment: It is typical [race condition problem](https://medium.com/in-the-weeds/fixing-a-race-condition-c8b475fbb994) There are some Technic for example [database locks](http://www.methodsandtools.com/archive/archive.php?id=83). It is depends on your envionment

Comment: Transaction processing

Comment: When person 1 presses the Buy button, the ticket is marked as Sold, even though the sale has not completed yet. If person 2 presses Buy, she finds that it's already been sold. If person 1 does not complete the purchase in a set time, the Sold flag is removed and the purchase cancelled.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has nothing to do with programming

Answer (score 1):

As soon as one person enters the workflow for purchase, flag that ticket as unavailable (with an expiration of some sort, perhaps 20 minutes), so that other shoppers cannot also purchase that ticket. If a second shopper tries to enter the purchase workflow, tell them the ticket is no longer available.

"Entering purchase workflow" is defined as a "critical section", where only one person is allowed to enter at a time. It will be impossible for two people to claim the last available ticket simultaneously.

When the first person makes the purchase, permanently decrement the available tickets. If the first person cancels the purchase or abandons the workflow, release the reserved ticket back into the available pool.

Comment: That's the way to do it. Technically this problem was solved in the 1960's - airline reservations systems (based on IBM's CICS, IMS/DC).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what kind of answer you expect to get, on the data base end or c# end.
in any case, the c# side should be very simple and look something like:

```
 private void Order_bt_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        DataTable data = ReadDataFromDB();

        if (data.Rows.Count <= 40)
        {
            // reserve the ticket to a person
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Sorry, the show is sold out");
        }

    }
```

Comment: This means: The show will hardly ever be sold out. Is that what you want?

Comment: At least he tried. Thanks man, but that don't will work with simultaneous buys.

Comment: rf1234, may I ask why? if every purchase is recorded on the database, eventually the maximum available tickets will be sold. unless I am missing something...